# How to resolve specific dependency of a dev dependency in a Yarn.lock

Tags: npm, yarnpkg, lerna, snyk

Trying to install a dev dependency but one of its dependencies is `lodash: 4.17.20`. When Snyk does a scan of my dependencies, it marks this dependency as a high security vulnerability.

How can we have this dev dependency try to resolve a different version of `lodash` for a dev dependency and pass the Snyk test?

Was thinking that in the `yarn.lock` file, it somehow needs to resolve a higher version of `lodash` for this dev dependency, so I've referred to https://classic.yarnpkg.com/en/docs/selective-version-resolutions/

Doing something in my `package.json` like

```
  "resolutions": {
    "**/lodash": "^4.17.20"
  }
```

Or

```
  "resolutions": {
    "<that dev dependency>/lodash": "^4.17.20"
  }
```

Seems like it hasn't quite worked, and the Yarn.lock hasn't updated the `lodash` dependency for that dev dependency.  Wanted to see if this was possible without updating the `yarn.lock` manually as I could see it being re-overwritten in the future.  This is done in a Lerna monorepo.

Answer (score 0):

Update from the Snyk team, they do not have monorepo support with Lerna as of 04/05/21